# default value of a list used as map value

Tags: c++, list, dictionary

Hi I was wondering if I have a map with int as element and list of int as value and I try to access to a key which is not in the map. The operator return a default value. But what is suppose to be a default value for a list ? the default constructor ?

Comment: Yes. The default value of *any* object is created by the no-arg constructor (or default constructor if you do not provide an explicit no-arg constructor).

Comment: A default list is just an empty one.

Comment: thanks a lot, I just need another precision. If a add a key value to the map inside a while are they delete when i leave the while or do they persist after it ?

Comment: Depends on the scope of the map. If the map's scope persists beyond the `while` loop, then yes, any changes you made to it will remain.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will default construct a list. [See here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5b%5d/).

If this is not the behaviour you want, you can use `std::map::at` ([see here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/at/)) instead of `std::map::operator[]` to access elements, which will throw an exception if the key doesn't exist, rather than inserting a new element.

Note: my answer assumes that you were referring to the `std` namespace in your question.

Answer (score 1):

If the `key` is not in the map than `operator []` inserts a new element with that `key` and uses the `default constructor`, which you can read more about [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5b%5d/)

The [default constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/list/) for `std::list` constructs an `empty` container.